# Martingale property of a stochastic integral w.r.t. a local martingale.

Tags: martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, local-martingales

I have some problems with the martingale property of a stochastic integral with respect to a continuous local martingale M. I know that if $X \in L^2(d[M])$
 then  $$ \int XdM$$ is a local martingale.
I wanted to know under which assumptions on X or M this integral is a proper martingale.

Comment: If $M$ is a martingale and $X \in L^2(d[M])$, then $\int X \, dM$ is a martingale.

Comment: Ok, and if M is just a local martingale, are there assumptions under which $\int XdM$ is a proper martingale?

Comment: Treat it like you would any other local martingale.